# Website deployment to China

Tags: deployment, azure, msdeploy, china

I'm trying to deploy a website to Azure China.
I just downloaded the publish profile from my Azure China account and use Visual Studio to deploy via Web Deploy using the profile, stock standard.
It used to work. But most of the time I'm getting an error:

```
5>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://testproj-che-staging-appserv.scm.chinacloudsites.cn/msdeploy.axd?site=testproj-ChE-Staging-AppServ ...
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Error ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID: Web deployment task failed. ( Could not connect to the remote computer ("testproj-che-staging-appserv.scm.chinacloudsites.cn"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.)
```

So I'm assuming that I'm just getting blocked by the great firewall of china.

How do I avoid connection termination?
Is there a workaround e.g. VPN?

Comment: Please discuss this with Azure support.

Comment: I've submitted a support ticket. I'm mostly worried, that it's outside of their control. That's why I'm seeking alternative ideas.